# to bail out vs to back out

Tags: meaning, expressions, synonyms, phrasal-verbs, computing

In computer science, I have often come across the expression *to back out* meaning to say that a function is returned from before performing its actual task, as in this imaginary code comment:

```
double divide(double dividend, double divisor) {
  if (divisor == 0) {
    return 0; //divisor is zero => back out early
  }
  return (dividend / divisor);
}
```

Now I recently came across the expression *to **bail** out* in just the very same context. I know that *to bail somebody out* generally means *to provide funds to get someone out of a difficult financial situation*, so I was wondering if the writer confused *to back out* and *to bail out* or if *to bail out* really has this meaning, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close as this specialised jargon (or even malapropism) is a more suitable fit on Computer Science.SE.

Comment: CS people will tell me off arguing this is a linguistic question.

Comment: Then why do they have a 'terminology' tag? Legalese, Ecclesiese,  most computerese ... are off-topic on ELU, which looks at standard usage.

Comment: How do I close this?

Comment: You have a 'close' option. I trust you'll get the correct answer on our sister site. You're very welcome to post suitable questions here (about general, even not-too-niche, English usage).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think this is a linguistics issue, Edwin. What the OP is really seeking is a meaning of "bail out". (Everyone knows what "back out" means). If you read Mortimer Graves answer below and my comment below that, you will see what I mean.

Comment: To "bail out" is to throw an exception.

Comment: To "back out" *might* mean to throw an exception but then have an exception handler that restores the conditions prior to the start of the difficulty.  Or more pedestrian back-out logic might be employed.

Comment: @WS2 If OP merely wants to know the usual meanings of 'bail out', a quick look in any dictionary will give the answer, so the correct procedure is to CV as lacking reasonable research, not answer. I gave OP the benefit of the doubt' and Hot Licks' 'throw an exception' claim seems to endorse this. A computing usage, wouldn't you now agree?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Be that as it may, it did seem to me that the meaning of "bail out" may have been a useful thing to discuss - particularly for any non-native speakers. I am always loathe to recommend closure of anything which provides an opportunity for people (including myself) to learn. I can never really fathom people (and there are a lot of them) whose first instinct on the site is to hit the abort button.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, the various non-computerese senses of 'bail/bale out' (the 'correct spelling' and etymology have already been covered on ELU) are interesting to discuss. But a dictionary readily supplies all the non-computerese answers, so the question should indicate why these aren't sufficient. And I'm not sure that ELL address such basic questions lacking any research shown. Why not ask the question there if you want further discussion?

Answer (score 2):

*OP: "I know that to bail somebody out generally means to provide funds to get someone out of a difficult financial situation"*

**Bail out** also means to quit something:
"The actor has bailed out of the film after only three weeks' shooting." *- Cambridge Dictionary*

The phrase is also often used with the specific meaning of leaving a crashing plane via parachute:
"The pilot barely had time to bail out" - also *Cambridge Dictionary*.

I'd suggest that the use of the phrase in a coding situation is along these lines.

Comment: But 'I'd suggest' ... answers are not what ELU is about.

Comment: Quite so. I think the parachute meaning is the relevant one here. I've looked in the OED, and as well as all the different financial, and legal senses of "bailing out banks"  the one that is equivalent to "back-out" is this one. *Aeronautics. An emergency parachute jump.1955   Sci. News Let. 8 Jan. 23   The purpose..was to explore human tolerances during a high speed bailout from jet planes.*

Comment: "Bail out" (in the parachute sense) == exception (in the programming sense).

Comment: "Bail out" in the banking sense == using a bucket to remove water from a leaky boat.

Comment: @HotLicks  I was going to add about the "leaky boat". I spent my boyhood next to a river, when boats were clinker-built, not of moulded fibreglass. So I know all about "bailing out". OED - *Now often less correctly bale v.3To lade or throw water out of a boat, etc., with buckets (formerly called bails), pails, basins, or other vessels.1614   S. Purchas Pilgrimage (ed. 2) ix. xiv. 911They bailed and pumped two thousand tuns, and yet were ten foot deep.1829   F. Marryat Naval Officer II. i. 14   One [man] to bail the water out.*

Comment: @HotLicks I have to correct you and say that "Bail out" == early exit (in the programming sense). It means that the conditions are such that the function does not need to do anything else. An exception, on the other hand, is when something actually goes _wrong_.

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco -- I suppose you've got me there ... I was only a programmer for about 45 years.

Comment: @HotLicks Well, thinking about it, you could "bail out" with an exception too! On reflection perhaps we could say that it's any sort of exit - exception or not.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I provided a referenced answer to the OP's question. It's only "I'd suggest" because I do not and cannot *know* why the author the OP was asking about used that phrase - but it seemed pretty clear that the intended meaning was a reference to "bail out" meaning quit - and likely a reference to parachutes, rather than "bail out" meaning save. (Also an ex-programmer.)

Comment: But a general enquiry about the meaning of 'bail out' is general reference, and asking about a computerese precising definition non-standard. // But do you disagree with HotLicks?

Comment: Fair enough. On the second, I completely agree with HotLicks that *bail out* is a sensible phrase to use for an early exit (either as the result of an exception or because a condition was fulfilled early). As an aside I'd note that I *wouldn't* use "back out" for that purpose as it has the alternate computerese meaning of undoing something, e.g. "the new code crashed so I backed out the changes".

Answer (score 1):

In computing, "to bail out" is "to exit early", for any reason, such as in your example. "To back out" generally has the meaning "to undo" changes, think `ROLLBACK` in SQL. `ROLLBACK` undoes and discards all current changes that have not yet been permanently committed (saved) to the database, returning it to its previous (stable) state.

Backing out should leave the program in a clean state, bailing out can leave the program in either a clean or an unstable state. Backing out is normally done carefully, bailing out is normally done quickly. For example, it might be desirable to restore the value of a changed variable on an error. Backing out will take care to do so, bailing out will exit as quickly as possible, potentially leaving a bad or invalid value in the variable.

Think of a plane on fire as a function about to crash the program. The program survives by bailing out with a parachute, but the function goes down in flames with the plane. (Actually, the function's run time and memory would be cleaned up and made inaccessible, equivalent to the plane being erased from existence before it has the chance to crash.)

Unfortunately, I can't find even bad references for either of these computing meanings, only blogs and the like showing them being used. If you'll forgive the original research:

> ## [A Taste of Recursion](https://www.dummies.com/programming/c/a-taste-of-recursion/)
>
> By Dan Gookin
>
> For recursion to work, the function must have a **bailout** condition, just like a loop. Therefore, either the value passed to the recursive function or its return value must be tested. Here’s a better example of a recursive function:
>
> ```
> void recursion(int x)
> {
>     if(x==0)
>         return;
>     else
>     {
>         puts("Boop!");
>         recursion(--x);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The recursion() function accepts the value x. If x is equal to zero, the function **bails**. Otherwise, the function is called again, but the value of x is reduced. The decrement prefix operator is used so that the value of x is reduced before the call is made.

(emphasis mine)

The meanings are very close to the standard English meanings:

> #### [bail out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bail-out)
>
> - to jump out of an aircraft with a parachute because the aircraft is going to have an accident
> - to stop doing or being involved with something
>
> #### [back out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/back-out)
>
> - to decide not to do something that you had said you would do
> - to refuse to do something you earlier had agreed to do

In my mind, they mean different but similar things in computing too. I could be wrong about their meanings not being interchangeable. Perhaps "to back out" of a function is acceptable technical English. If one of my colleagues wrote one where I thought they meant the other, I would certainly ask them to clarify it since clarity is one of the most important things in computing. However, others may differ from my viewpoint.